# How format an iPhone with code?

Tags: iphone

I have a problen! I give my little cousin my iPhone one aftermoon and when he returned it saw that my iPhone had a password and he can't remeber the code that he put!!! so I need to know how can I do to find or format my iPhone without the code, thanks.

Comment: :-) The humor section of stackoverflow

Comment: why do people let their kids (or little cousins) play with their iPhones?

Comment: no need to downvote him cause you have a problem with him formatting a phone.

Comment: wrong site, not programming related. If it's your iphone you should be able to restore from a backup on your itunes.

Comment: This would probably be a better question for superuser.com or another sister site.

Comment: indeed it would, therefore downvoted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your phone into DFU mode and then restore it through iTunes

How to put your phone into DFU mode:

-plug in iPhone to your computer-

1.) Hold home button + power button for about 10 seconds (wait about a second after the phone turns off)

2.) Release power button and continue holding home button until iTunes recognizes it in "recovery mode"

3.) Press restore in iTunes

Answer (score 0):

you can do a Hard Reset of the iphone

Hold down the power button and the home button till the phone is completely off and stops restarting...

Then Holding the Home Button press the power button to turn the phone on.

Keep the home button held till you see the Connect to Itunes Image.

Connect it to itunes and it will tell you that you must recover the phone.